# Get the active rows in Google Spreadsheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am able to get correctly the starting and ending rows that user has selected if the range is continuous:

[image]

Here is the code I use:

```
var sa = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var range = sa.getActiveRange();
Browser.msgBox("first_row: " + range.getRowIndex() + ", last_row: " + range.getLastRow());
```

The problem is when the user has selected non-continuous range:

[image]

`range.getRow()` and `range.getRowIndex()` both report `4` as starting row. Is there a way to get what exactly the user has selected?. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there a way to get what exactly the user has selected?

No, not currently. You might want to star [this feature request](https://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=4069&q=get%20range&colspec=Stars%20Opened%20ID%20Type%20Status%20Summary%20Component%20Owner) to be able to get multiple non-contiguous ranges.

Comment: I was suspecting this. Thanks anyways :)